# css selector for div with 'display: table-cell'

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have html that looks like:

```
<div style="display: table">
  <div style="display: table-row">
     <div style="display: table-cell">
       ... some content
     </div>
     <div style="display: table-cell">
       second cell content
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I'm searching for css selector that would match all divs that have `display: table-cell` style. Is it possible?

Comment: Couldn't you just change the HTML markup?

Comment: @Chrisstar In my case it's generated html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this

```
div[style*="display:table-cell"]
```

Comment: @gawi Careful that this selector would work only if the style is inline.

Comment: Also i read that blank spaces etc. so watch out